# Call function inside RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to create an object inside RequireJS?

Because, in this way, `FunctionA` is visible inside the `Click` event:

```
require(["library1", "library2"], function (obj1) {
    $('#loginButton').click(function () {
        functionA();
    });
    functionA() {
        obj1.value;
    }
});
```

But if i do something like this, it doesn't work:

```
var library = new library();
require(["library1", "library2"], function (obj1) {
    $('#loginButton').click(function () {
        library.functionA();
    });
});

function library() {
    this.functionA = function () {
        obj1.value;
    }
}
```

or

```
var library = new library();
$('#loginButton').click(function () {
    library.functionA();
});

functionA() {
    require(["library1", "library2"], function (obj1) {
        this.functionA = function () {
            obj1.value;
        }
    });
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look [Passing Parameters to Require.js module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382291/passing-parameters-to-require-js-module)

Comment: I don't think he's making a module though, he's inline `require`ing.  I would think that `library` would be captured for the closure created in the `require` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your explicit example is not working.  However, I would suggest ensuring that you make `jQuery` a dependency in your `require` statement.

The following is using `dojo`, which uses an `AMD` environment like `RequireJS`.  I just wanted to make sure that I was able to load multiple modules for my example and `RequireJS` has not modules with it like `dojo` does.

I was able to get your second example working by fixing the dependencies.

```js
var library = new library();

require(["dojo/dom", "jquery"], function(dom, $) {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    library.functionA();
  });
});

function library() {
  this.functionA = function() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
  var dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    isDebug: true,
    async: 1,
    packages: [{
      name: "jquery",
      location: "//code.jquery.com",
      main: "jquery-1.11.3.min"
    }]
  };
</script>

<!-- Include the dojo 1.10.4 CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


<main>
  <button id="button" type="button">Click me</button>
</main>
```